# Is there a topology on the reals such that addition is continuous but not multiplication? What about conversely?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, real-numbers

Is there a topology $T$ on the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ such that the binary operation of addition is continuous under $T$, but the binary operation of multiplication is not continuous under $T$? And, what about conversely? That is, is there a topology on the set of real numbers such that multiplication is continuous but addition is not continuous?

Comment: Here’s a very cheap answer: consider the topology generated by all intervals $[a,b)$ with $a < b$. Addition is clearly continuous: the topology is translation-invariant, so we only need to check at zero, and $[0,u/2)+[0,u/2) \subset [0,u)$. 

However, it’s easy to see that $x \longmapsto -x$ is not continuous (the inverse image of $[0,1)$ is $(-1,0]$ which is not a neighborhood of $0$), so the multiplication map cannot be continuous. 

I do not know what happens if we require $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to be a topological group for the topology.

Comment: For “multiplication without addition”, I think the topology generated by all the $[0,a]$ and $[-a,0]$ (for $a>0$) works…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Addition without substraction**: consider the topology generated by all intervals $[a,b)$ with $a < b$. Addition is clearly continuous: the topology is translation-invariant, so we only need to check at zero, and $[0,u/2)+[0,u/2) \subset [0,u)$.

However, it’s easy to see that $x \longmapsto -x$ is not continuous (the inverse image of $[0,1)$ is $(-1,0]$ which is not a neighborhood of $0$), so the multiplication map cannot be continuous.

---

**Topological group but not multiplication**: endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the coarsest topology making the projection $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ continuous, where $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is *discrete*.

Then the open subsets are exactly the subsets stable under translation by $\mathbb{Z}$.

It’s easy to check that $\mathbb{R}$ is a topological group for this topology. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is open, while $2\mathbb{Z}$ isn’t, so that $x \longmapsto x/2$ is not continuous in this topology – hence the multiplication map isn’t continuous either.

---

**Multiplication without addition**: consider the topology generated by the $[0,a]$ and $[-a,0]$ for $a>0$. The product should be continuous for this topology, but not the sum: any neighborhood of $(1,-1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ must contain $[0,1] \times [-1,0]$, so its image under the sum map is $[-1,1]$, which is not contained in
all the neighborhoods of $0$.